# How to do translation elegant?

Tags: php, translation

We are currently working on a custom php framework, with multilanguage feature. So far its easy to handle translations, but now we have more complex messages with links. For example, this:

```
"hello user <a href="/register">register</a> here!"
```

could be translated with included HTML tags?

```
"fkds vkelip <a href="/register">regiximi</a> fácő ea!"
```

Or I should do this in 3 steps:

```
"hello user" -> translation
"register" -> translation
"here" -> translation
```

?

Comment: use one of the many i18n libraries around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) extension.

Answer (score 1):

you should use gettext function which handles all your translation requirements. as most of the current cms and framework does .

```
"<?=__('hello user')?> <a href="/register"><?=__('register')?></a> <?=__('here!')?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put all text into the translate function because it's the whole sentence:

```
__('hello user <a href="/register">register</a> here!');
```